# Correct way to write where statement with array of values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I can't figure out the correct way to write this where statement for my controller in one line.

What am I missing here?

```
@food_ranks = FoodRank.where("user_id = ? AND rank = ?", current_user.id, [0, 1, 2])
```

Here is my attempt to write it in 3 lines.

```
@food_ranks = Array.new(FoodRank.where("user_id = #{current_user.id} AND rank = 0"))
@food_ranks << FoodRank.where("user_id = #{current_user.id} AND rank = 1")
@food_ranks << FoodRank.where("user_id = #{current_user.id} AND rank = 2")
```

`@food_ranks` correctly displays the objects like this. Why wont it let me do something like this now?

```
 @food_rank each do |rank|
   rank.user_id
 end
```

Is it making `@food_ranks` literally the where statement? (undefined method)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this way:

```
@food_ranks = FoodRank.where("user_id = ? AND rank IN (?)", current_user.id, [0, 1, 2])
```

You can also do:

```
@food_ranks = FoodRank.where(user_id: current_user.id, rank: [0, 1, 2])
```

Comment: You don't have to write `rank IN (?)` for the top one, Rails will generate it for you.

Comment: I think, for the first query, that's still needed. For the 2nd one, you don't need that. That's why I did not use `IN` in the 2nd query, Rails will automatically do that.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are passing in an array, and trying to compare rank to that.

Try changing it like so:

```
FoodRank.where("user_id = ?", current_user.id, rank: [0, 1, 2])
```

Rails will automatically generate the SQL `IN` statement from the array, so no need to specify that.